# createProcedure and dropProcedure attributes

Tags: liquibase

I have a couple of questions with regards to the createProcedure and dropProcedure commands.  They do not seem to have some attributes that I would expect to see.  Maybe I am missing something.
 - First when using the createProcedure command it does not handle comments in the stored procedure code.  I noticed that the sqlFile command has a 'stripComments' attribute but it does not seem to work either. Is there a way to handle comments in the stored procedure code?
 - Second the dropProcedure command does not have any way to indicate 'if exists' as far as I can tell. I am just running a strait sql command to do the drop procedure which works but having the specific dropProcedure command seems pointless if there is not an if exists attribute or something.

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten  the comments to work.  There has to be a space after the comment delimiter.  I.E.  -- this is my comment